# Deserialization using Externalizable interface in Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm learning about Serializable and Externalizable interface and I see that, when an Externalizable object is reconstructed, an instance is created first using the public no-arg constructor, then the readExternal method is called. If the object does not support Externalizable, then Serializable objects are restored by reading them from an ObjectInputStream.

I don't understand why we use ObjectInputStream for Externalization if the object isn't readed from there? What exactly is readed from the ObjectInputStream? I think we read something from there if we use it.

Also I found this chart about Deserialization Externalizable or Serializable interface

[image]

What is the difference between Serializable and Externalizable at the deserialization process?

I don't understand why the Externalizable objects aren't restored by reading them from an ObjectInputStream in the same way like Serializable objects?

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("employee.ser"))
```

I know that the FileInputStream opens a file, creates a sequence of bytes based on the data in the file. The ObjectInputStream takes a sequence of bytes, recreats the object based on the sequence of bytes.

And here is a code.

```
import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;

public class Employee implements Externalizable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public void Employee() {


    } 

    public int getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {

        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {

        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {

        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput oo) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Inside writeExternal method");
        oo.writeInt(id); 
        oo.writeObject(name); 
    }

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput oi) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Inside readExternal method");
        id = oi.readInt();
        name = (String) oi.readObject();
    }
}
```

ExternalizableWrite

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class ExternalizableWrite {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ExternalizableWrite ew = new ExternalizableWrite();
        ew.writeEmployeeObject();
    }

    private void writeEmployeeObject() {

        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("employee.ser"))) {

            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setId(101);
            employee.setName("Peter"); 
            employee.setAge(25); 

            System.out.println(employee);

            oos.writeObject(employee);  // write the specified object to the ObjectOutputStream

            System.out.println("Successfully written employee object to the file.\n");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s", ex); 

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s", ex); 
        }
    }
}
```

ExternalizableRead

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class ExternalizableRead {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ExternalizableRead er = new ExternalizableRead();
        er.readEmployeeObject();
    }

    private void readEmployeeObject() {

        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("employee.ser"))) {

            Employee employee = (Employee) ois.readObject();

            System.out.println(employee);

            System.out.println("Successfully read employee objecct to the file.\n");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s", ex);

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {

            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s", ex);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between Serializable and Externalizable at the deserialization process?

According to the implementation of `ObjectInputStream`, `Externalizable` objects are handled differently than `Serializable` objects, as expected:

```
if (desc.isExternalizable()) {
    readExternalData((Externalizable) obj, desc);
} else {
    readSerialData(obj, desc);
}
```

As you might expect, the `readExternalData` method calls `Externalizable#readExternal` for the object that is being deserialized, while the `readSerialData` method simply deserializes the serialized fields.

> I don't understand why we use ObjectInputStream for Externalization if the object isn't readed from there?

I'm not sure what you're asking, but `ObjectInputStream` **does** handle `Externalizable` objects, as seen above.

> I don't understand why the Externalizable objects aren't restored by reading them from an ObjectInputStream in the same way like Serializable objects?

Because `Externalizable` objects force you to manually serialize and deserialize them, whereas `Serializable` attempts to serialize all non-static and non-transient fields.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why we use ObjectInputStream for Externalization if the object isn't readed from there?

Externalizable also uses `ObjectInputStream`. 

`ObjectInputStream` is the parameter that is passed to the `readExternal` method. One may use methods such as `readInt`,`readFloat` etc of the ObjectInputStream to read the values from the serialized object.

> What is the difference between Serializable and Externalizable at the deserialization process?

A class (implementing `Serializable` interface) can customize the data written the serialized object by using the following methods:

`private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException`

`private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;`

Suppose that there are classes A and B like this

```
  class A implement Serializable {
     writeObject(...){....}
     readObject(...){....}
  } 

  class B extends A implements Serializable{
     writeObject(...){....}
     readObject(...){....}
  }
```

When an object of B is serialized/de-serialized then `writeObject`/`readObject` methods of parent/super class A is called before that of B, thus allowing for parent class' to decide which fields to serialize/de-serialize.

But, when it comes to `Externalizable`, this does not happen. Only sub-class's `readExternal` and `writeExternal` methods are called, overriding the parent's serialization/de-serialization behaviour.